# Symfony2 routing pattern route not found

Tags: php, symfony, routes

i have a very simple understanding question

isnt it possible to have such routing patterns ?

```
foobar_foobar_videos_all:
    pattern:  /video
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideos }

foobar_foobar_videos_by_category:
    pattern:  /video/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideosByCategory }

foobar_foobar_videos_by_category_and_offset:
    pattern:  /video/{category}/page/{offset}
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideosByCategory }
```

this way the first route doesnt work, printing

```
"No route found for "GET /video"
```

while the others work perfect.

How can i route to /video ?

Comment: got the solution myself, i simply neede to put the first route beneath the others

Comment: can you please post it as an answer and then mark that answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put it the /video pattern to the end

```
foobar_foobar_videos_by_category:
    pattern:  /video/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideosByCategory }

foobar_foobar_videos_by_category_and_offset:
    pattern:  /video/{category}/page/{offset}
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideosByCategory }

foobar_foobar_videos_all:
    pattern:  /video
    defaults: { _controller: foobarfoobarBundle:Content:showVideos }
```